# Backbone Design - Large application, data as needed

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

I have a Backbone design pattern question.

Say I have a very large app, I am talking around 30 models, a lot more views and components.

My design problem is this:

I can not bootstrap the data. This app is 100% API driven, I can also not fetch all of the entities in one go (talking thousands of instances per database table). And I can not cleanly do a separation of applications into smaller modules, as each heavily rely on all of the models, and collections.

At the moment I have got controllers which I have a dispatcher teardown and setup each controller as needed. The controllers job is to create the models, and fetch all of the required data to fulfil that screen. Then the views render.

This method is starting to prove problem some, and am looking for some advice regarding applications of this size.

The other solution I had though of would be to scrap the Controller doing the fetching and moving such logic to the Views. However, each view has a lot of children views which also require this data. Would it be better to have those sub-views spawn ASAP then get them to fetch their own required data (and implement a caching mechanism), or to have the parent spawn the sub-views once it gets the data returned (I understand each have their use cases).

Example site:

http://themotorfeed.com/

Comment: What is the nature of the problems that are creeping up with your current design? Performance?

Comment: @mjswensen the two biggest problems are: 1. keeping it DRY. Sometimes I have to perform a fetch in the controller so that I can update the url, update the page title. But I might need to perform the fetch again due to a View event requiring fresh data. 2. Making it so that events clean up nicely. Let's say I have View A with sub-view B. When an action swaps out View A with another View C I have harvest any views which are reused. This in theory is fine, but I can not know if View B should persist until I have the data from the controller, which will of course fire events and could break things

Comment: @mjswensen I have edited to give an example site with this in use.
If you go to https://themotorfeed.com/users/jshthornton then click the car icon (garage) I keep persisted the user panel.